# AWS EC2 Java SDK: Start an instance with custom instance type

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to start an EC2 instance though Java code. I added this maven dependency in my project:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/1.11.308

It provides me with a class, which can be used to request starting an instance. The code is as follows:

```
StartInstancesRequest startReq = new StartInstancesRequest()
                .withInstanceIds(instanceID);

ec2Client.startInstances(startReq);
```

But, there is no `with*` method in `StartInstancesRequest` class, which takes instance type as input.

Can anyone please tell me how can I specify instance type too?

Answer (score 0):

The `startInstances` call is really used to start instances that are in the stopped state - that's why it takes instance ids.

I use [runInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#runInstances-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RunInstancesRequest-) when I want to customize the instance.  With it you can do things like:

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-4b814f22")
                   .withInstanceType("m1.small")
                   .withMinCount(1)
                   .withMaxCount(1)
                   .withKeyName("my-key-pair")
                   .withSecurityGroups("my-security-group");
```

(taken directly from [Run an Amazon EC2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/run-instance.html)).

This has tons of customization that you can use to configure the new instance.

Comment: Creating an instance from an image looks expensive. How much time (from your experience) it takes to create an instance from AMI?

Comment: A minute or so usually.  Starting a stopped machine is faster but you can't customize very much once it has initially been launched.  The traditional way to make this as fast as possible is with a custom AMI that has all of your software already installed and available as soon as the instance starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AMI and use the runInstances, why not change the instance type before you start your instance as follows

```
// Change the instance type
ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest modReq = new ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest()
.withInstanceType(instanceType)
.withInstanceId(instanceID);

ec2client.modifyInstanceAttribute(modReq);

// Then start your instance
StartInstancesRequest startReq = new StartInstancesRequest()
            .withInstanceIds(instanceID);

ec2Client.startInstances(startReq);
```